# Big O complexity of three nested loops with the last loop in an if statement

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Suppose we have the following block of code:

```
sum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if(i == j)
            for(k = 0; k < n; k++)
                sum++;
```

In the book I'm reading it's stated that the complexity is O(n^2), thetha (n^2) to be precise, but I'm not sure why. When trying to calculate it myself I get O(n^3):

1. Outer loop complexity is O(n)
2. By the second loop the complexity gets to O(nˆ2) by following the nested loops rule
3. The if statement would be true n times, so by the third loop the complexity would be O(n*nˆ2)
4. The sum++ statement takes constant time, so complexity stays at O(nˆ3)

That's my logic, but it's flawed it seems. What is the reasoning for the O(n^2) complexity here?

Comment: Looks close to the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59015083/3440545).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second loop runs `n` steps. Each step takes only constant time (evaluating the if statement) except for one step. The `i`-th step takes `O(n)` because the third loop is executed. So the second loop takes `2n = O(n)` in total. So in total you get `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite get why the second loop is O(2n). The whole if statement is  O(n), right? And woudn't that make the second loop O(n*n) instead of O(2n)?

Comment: I think I get it now. So the if statement has indeed an O(n) complexity, but the second loop's complexity becomes `O(n + 1 + ... + 1 + n + 1 + ... + 1) = 0(n)` following from the fact that the if would be true only one time per loop.